# Difference between derivative of a function at a point and limit of the differentiated function at that point

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

$f'(x_0)\;=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$
While solving a question:

> Prove that the function {$f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}\; \; \forall x\neq0$ and $f(x) =0 \;\;\forall x=0$} is not differentiable  at 0.

I have done it by evaluating derivative from the left and right individually which gives $\infty$. So, I have concluded that $f$ is not differentiable at 0.

But I  noticed that $f'(x)=0\;\;\;\forall x\neq0$. So, shouldn't the limit of $f'(x)$  be $0$? I know that I have made a false argument. Please tell me where is contradiction in my argument.

Edit:  In short, what is the difference between $f'(0)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f'(x)$?

Comment: How is $f(0)$ defined?

Comment: $f$ is not even *defined* at $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it now.

Comment: What is $\lim \frac {f(\frac 1 n) -f(0)} {1/n-0}$?

Comment: Parameterise the function for $x>0$, $x=0$ and $x<0$. The answer will be obvious then.

Comment: Existence of $\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x)$ does not guarantee existence of $f'(x_0)$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy. It is $0$. The question is as $f'(x)=0\;\;\forall x\neq0$. So, using this I get $f'(0)=0. I want to know what is wrong in this approach?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, *always* check continuity of the function *before* differentiability. The definition of derivative is not reasonable if the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the correct computations: the limit is $\infty$, so the derivative does not exist.

Now, when everything is nice, the derivative exists *and* it is continuous, so the derivative coincides with the limit of the derivatives at nearby points.

My guess is that you are asking for an intuition of what fails when things are not nice. Intuitions are subjective, so I am going to give you mine: geometry. Do not think of the derivative as a number, but as a mechanism to build the tangent line, which is a (linear) approximation to the function. The number you obtain as the derivative is the slope of this line, but the line is also characterized by the point it is attached to.

In this case, you should plot the function. You would see you could place a horizontal line approximating the function at both sides of $0$, but these lines are placed on *different* points. Since the approximation does not work the same way from both sides, it cannot exist.

So, if I propose this exercise in a test, your answer would be correct, but it is *not* the answer I am expecting and it would be somehow considered as lacking intuition (and wasting time with the limit). The "correct" answer (in my opinion) is: the function is not continuous at 0, so the derivative cannot exist.

Comment: Wonderful explanation. After reading your answer, I have come to the conclusion that for $f'(0)$ we have to concern about the limit of  $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$(which doesn't exist) not $\lim\limits_{x \to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ because both these are different functions and in graph of f'(x) we plot only their limit not the whole function which is written after limit. So the graph I think I have misinterpreted. I think this is wrong in my thinking, doesn't it?

Comment: @lti I am not sure I follow. The graph of $f'(x)$ as a function of $x$ has nothing to do with the graph of the tangent line at $x=0$. The former considers a neighbourhood, the latter is *local*. The point is this function is ill-behaved only at $x=0$.

Comment: We can use example of $f(x)=x^2$. $f'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\frac{x^2-x_0^2}{x-x_0}$ which is equal to $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}$$(x+x_0)$. In graph of $f'(x)$ we don't plot $x+x_0$ but its limit which when plotted for all points gives the function 2x. Similarly in my question $f'(0)$ is not defined at 0. But at all other points it is 0. The plot of $\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}$ is entirely different from $\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ but in my question(by chance same)but we only bother about there limit at 2 and 1 respectively which is 0. I think this conclusion is right?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{1}{|x|} \to \infty$ as $x \to 0.$

Hence, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: The question is what is the difference between $f′(0)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f′(x)$?